# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long - client and server SSL certs for the same IP

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, fqdn

I'm implementing mutual SSL between service A and service B. Service A uses both 1-way and 2-way SSL. 1-way for the communication between a user and website A, and 2-way SSL to forward requests from that user to the service B in a secure way.

1-way SSL in service A is specified in Tomcat server.xml. 2-way SSL is implemented using JSEE secure socket communication on the client side (service A), and Tomcat config (service B). Atm. when I try to access service A I get **ssl_error_rx_record_too_long** error.

According to this answer [ssl_error_rx_record_too_long and Apache SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl) one of the reasons may be the fact that I'm using more than one SSL certificate for the same IP. Is this really the case that you can't use the same IP for several certificates? Even if one certificate is a server certificate (for 1-way SSL) and another is a client certificate (for 2-way SSL)?

This may not be the cause of my problem, but I just want to make sure if **it's actually possible to have several certificates for the same FQDN**. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

`ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` generally has nothing to do with certificate configuration, but the fact that what's talking on that port isn't actually using SSL/TLS.

The answers (and even the update to the question) in the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl) also point to this problem (e.g. missing `SSLEngine on`). You probably forgot something like `SSLEnabled="true"` in your connector configuration.

As I was saying in [an answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637323/372643), being able to configure two server certificates on the same IP address isn't really a problem for your case.

> it's actually possible to have several certificates for the same FQDN

It is possible to configure multiple certificates on the same IP address and port using the Server Name Indication TLS extension, but both servers and clients would need to support it. In particular, this is not supported by the JSSE in Java 7 on the server side (only on the client side), but there are workarounds if you're willing to put a reverse proxy in front of your Java server.

This wouldn't be possible to do this with the *same* FQDN, since it's what allows to pick the certificate. This being said, having multiple server certificates for the same FQDN on the same IP address is generally pointless. Supporting multiple certificates is precisely useful when you need to support distinct names.