# ssl error, record too long (localhost)

Tags: php, apache, google-app-engine, localhost

Installed google app engine and when I run localhost my page is not displayed. I get this error

```
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

How can I fix this? And if I try running the app on port 453 I get the erorr

> Unable to bind to port...

How can I fix this?

Comment: There are some interesting answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl

Comment: Do you have a Minecraft server running on your computer? It seems that  port 453 is commonly used by that. Why do you want to run the dev_appserver on that port, why not use the defaults? https://www.google.com/search?q=port+453+creative+server

Comment: When I run on the default ports I get this error "(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)".When I remove s from https i.e I open http:localhost:8080 the page is displayed, but then my bootstrap does not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dev_appserver that comes with GAE SDK does not support SSL. You'll need to access via http instead.