# visiting 'localhost:8080/signin' gives me Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: django, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I have a google appengine project running in localhost. Everything works fine until i go to the 'login' page. When i go there i get the following error:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8080. SSL received
>   a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
>
> ```
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could 
> not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

the appengine command i use to run the project is dev_appserver.py" --host 127.0.0.1 . This is run pycharm. This only occurs in the 'login' endpoint and no other endpoint.

The console error i get is:

```
default: "GET /signin HTTP/1.1" 301 -
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing arises because `dev_appserver` does not support SSL. You  can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661082/ssl-error-record-too-long-localhost) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849020/gae-dev-appserver-py-over-https) where similar questions were asked.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app) suggests to use standard python development tools for testing, such as Flask or Django built-in development servers. This could be a better try to test your application thoroughly.

Sidenote: If you search the internet you can find some articles offering workarounds like setting a reverse proxy. IMHO I would advice to follow the documentation.

Comment: unfortunately i have tried to the application using python development tools. However, it is an old project that is much more of a hacked together API then a Django/Flask application; i cannot get it to run without using dev_appeserver; my option is to set up a reverse proxy but i cannot find any resources on how to setup a reverse proxy in windows.  If it is possible, can you recommend some?

Comment: I have found the following links: a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849020/gae-dev-appserver-py-over-https), an [article](https://nickolaskraus.org/articles/using-ssl-tls-with-the-google-app-engine/) and a [Github project](https://github.com/cameronhunter/local-ssl-proxy). I would try first with the Github one. Bear in mind this approach is not assured to work and that setting a second project for development purposes would be the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this issue. For me, it appeared when some erroneous code was trying to redirect to `HTTPS` when I was running app on localhost on port 4500 which doesn't support SSL. I just change the app URL to `http` and worked fine.

In your case too, on the first image as I can see the request URL is something like `https://localhost:8080/sign` is this normal? I think you have to change this to `http://localhost:8080/sign`.