# Embedding website to facebook. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Tags: facebook

I created a facebook application with a page. But when i'm accessing the application it gave me the error as stated in the title

I hope someone could help me with this. 
Thanks.

Comment: looks like SSL is not set up correctly

Comment: It is? But why when im trying to visit the website manually it seems fine.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/975148

Comment: lots of results on that error with google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl