# Magento - Secure Connection Failed

Tags: php, magento, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a magento application. The client application is based on a https:// based URL. When I upload my magento application to my server it displays the following error:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to subdomain.myserver.info. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: I removed random chit-chat. When writing a question, please focus on laying out all relevant information as short as possible. Random chit-chat as "hi", or "thanks in advance" may seem polite, but clutter up the question. This causes the question to be less clear than when they are not included.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl

Answer (score 0):

Just Contact to Web Hosting Company.

And tell them to Install SSL Certificate on your Web Hosting.

Error will be removed automatically.

Thanks