# WampServer HTTPS "refused to connect" / "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"

Tags: ssl-certificate, wamp, wampserver

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312), I created:

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\ssl.crt\vhost.crt` & 
`C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\ssl.key\vhost.key`

I edited:

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-ssl` to include:

```
<VirtualHost www.vhost.dev:443>

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/vhostdev"
ServerName www.vhost.dev:443
ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/ssl_error.log"
TransferLog "c:/wamp/logs/ssl_error.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/vhost.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.key/vhost.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/vhostdev">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

The SSL Apache module is turned on.

www.vhost.dev is defined in the Windows host file correctly.

When I load https://www.vhost.dev, I receive:

```
This site can’t be reached
www.vhost.dev refused to connect.
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

There is nothing in `C:\wamp\logs\apache_error.txt`

There is nothing in `Windows Event Viewer > Application`.

Help appreciated.

***Update***: I created a 2nd `.crt` & `.key` for a 2nd vhost and the problem followed me when I tried to load the 2nd vhost over `https`. This problem has only existed since I reinstalled Windows from fresh.

***Update 2***: After running `netsh int ipv4 install` in Windows `cmd`, the error has changed to:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

***Update 3***: In another browser, Firefox, the error is different:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.vhost.dev. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

***Update4***: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG has a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762977/667903) but none of the solutions in the answer or answer comments applied.

***Update 5***: I upgraded from WAMPServer 2.5 to WAMPServer 3, and the issue remains.

***Update 6***: I had found that I had keys and certificates referenced in `<VirtualHost>` entries in `httpd-ssl.conf` that were not present in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\ssl.crt` or `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\ssl.key`.

These `<VirtualHost>` entries were from my previous Windows 10 installation.

I commented out the erroneous entries, so that the only `<VirtualHost>` entries left are those that have valid .`crt` and `.key` files. However, the same error `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` remains in Firefox.

Comment: Seems apache is not listening to port 443.
check this http://serverfault.com/a/475130, might be helpful to you

Comment: Thank you @Rajesh. I've added `Listen 10.1.1.1:443` where `10.1.1.1` is my host IP address. I now receive: `This site can’t provide a secure connection. www.vhost.dev sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. I click diagnose in Chrome, and the Windows Troubleshooter opens, but [can't fix the errors - see screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/7FouvZy.png).

Comment: I try to reinstall TCP/IP 4, but receive [this error](https://i.imgur.com/Pu97Wql.png). I try to reinstall Winsock using the MajorGeeks tool from this [SuperUser thread](http://superuser.com/questions/1007325/blocked-by-group-policy-trying-to-install-tcp-ipv4-windows-10), but it does not resolve the browser `https` error.

Comment: Check [One or more network protocols are missing..](http://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/36238-one-more-network-protocols-missing-solution.html)

Comment: Try adding `localhost:443` and see

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. No change unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @AniMenon, after running `netsh int ipv4 install` and rebooting, the error has changed (see my edit to the question please), and no network issues are detected when running the network troubleshooter when prompted by Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Does the request hit APache in the first place (check logs!). YOu sure it isn't a firewall problem? ALso, does the Apache error log say anything?

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. In Firefox, I receive a different error. See `Update 3` above in the question please.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesH. No, the access logs have not been updated since the PC started Wampserver 11 hours ago.

Comment: I assume thats WAMPServer 2.5! Any reason you dont install WAMPServer3?

Comment: Maybe the issue is with your certificate

Comment: I upgraded to WAMPServer3 and the issue remains @RiggsFolly.

Comment: I recreated the certificate and the issue remains (`SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` in Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

Well following [my own tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312) it works just fine.

The only difference I see is in the SSL Virtual Host definition

My `httpd-ssl.conf` looks like this:

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4

SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:d:/wamp/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/wamphelpers"
    ServerName www.wamphelpers.dev:443
    ServerAdmin nopwd@homemail.net
    ErrorLog "d:/wamp/logs/wamphelpers-error.log"
    TransferLog "d:/wamp/logs/wamphelpers-access.log"

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "d:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.20/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "d:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.20/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "d:/wamp/www/wamphelpers">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "d:/wamp/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

and the only REAL difference seems to be that you used

```
<VirtualHost www.vhost.dev:443>
```

and I used

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

I did have to download a new version of OpenSSL-Win32 which ment that I had to copy the new versions of `libaey32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` into all the versions of PHP that I have available on my system.

If you have to do this remember these 2 files must be copied into

```
\wamp\bin\php\php{version}
```

and **NOT** the `apache\bin` folder.

You should then do

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9 (click on the version number)
```

(or whatever version you are currently running)

to cause WAMPServer to set the symlinks correctly to the new files.

Comment: Thanks Riggs. I do have several local vhosts, hence I don't think I can use `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` for each of these.