# After adding SSL with cloudfare, the JS does not work and this error occurs in Network,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, socket.io

So i added SSL with cloudfare to my site but all the JS no longer works. I have set all links in the source code to https but that didnt work.

The server is running apache2 on debian 7

I get this error however, maybe someone will understand it?

[Error Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viylS.png),
[Error Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPNGu.png)

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/jcanvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/tinysort.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/expanding.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/notify.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/plot.js?v=<?=time()?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/graph.js?v=<?=time()?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/settings.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/app.js?v=<?=time()?>"></script>
```

Comment: Please add the `error` and also provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: im not sure what code is causing it ://

Comment: [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl) that has the same error `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssl\_error\_rx\_record\_too\_long and Apache SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide littel more detail. Path of one of your JS(not loading) may be.

Comment: is that what you want?

Comment: https://csgo-cade.com/

is this you domain??

I have checked all your js are loading perfectly fine on your site.

Comment: The games do not play though? Did you log in? When visiting through the IP you can see the site works http://prntscr.com/ijtyo0 But when visiting through https it doesn't... http://prntscr.com/ijtzh5